# encrypt my internet upload and download packets

Tags: internet, encryption

Is there a software can help me to encrypt any upload or download made from the internet ?

Comment: Is this a programming question? If not then it's destined for Super User.

Comment: Can clarify more? Is this a programming language question or for a specific tool?

Answer (score 3):

Potentially you could use a VPN or ssh tunnel to some remote location.  This would encrypt your internet traffic between your own computer and that remote location.  The traffic would be unencrypted between the remote location and the destination server, however.

If you're attempting to prevent someone with administrative access to your local network from spying on your traffic, this type of solution may be sufficient.

In addition to the software, you'll need a remote system running the same software to route your traffic.  Probably the easiest way to acheive this is to set up a cheap web hosting account with a host that supports ssh (most Linux/Unix hosts-- pair.com, dreamhost, many others) and then use a program like PuTTY to make the tunnelled connections.

Answer (score 2):

No. In order for a transmission to be encrypted, both the receiver and the sender have to know how to encrypt/decrypt the message, and agree on it beforehand. You can't force it to happen.

Answer (score 2):

There is such a software: all kinds of VPN. There is only one condition: both ends of transmission have to use it. :).

Answer (score 0):

TOR or any other onion skin router network would do it, at least for anything you configured to use it (most things can be).

http://www.torproject.org/